# Meteor 1.7 Blank Page Issue

Tags: webpack, meteor, babeljs, ecma

Seriously need help here.

I was migrating my Meteor project from 1.4.2 to 1.6.x but to no success.  Then I am at 1.7 now.  Though I managed to overcome the possible incompatibility issues to no more, however when I try to run as localhost:3000, main page turned blank. I believe something not write but any clue how could I effectively troubleshoot it?

Below shows how the HTML looks like when viewing source:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>WEB CRM</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/crm/favicon.ico"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ce98c502c7.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.7%22%2C%22meteorEnv%22%3A%7B%22NODE_ENV%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22TEST_METADATA%22%3A%22%7B%7D%22%7D%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isModern%22%3Atrue%7D"))</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?hash=877fff3b616c6755a6af252aba6f0bba0eff24ef"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-css.js?hash=aa0c85de60fbfb6f70547adf05dfdadec5662dd6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-js.js?hash=c01d59f5db2a34f8efd70e6ad29591e0e31e7cac"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=9d656f3a1f7103263d5f43af7cccb38122bcdaf0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules.js?hash=b0f78ebc59e153336982112cde7d5b89cf93c49a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/es5-shim.js?hash=58f6bd3ca35ce16465a64a7de292ad5e20b7e463"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modern-browsers.js?hash=2f0f8e122b18f2a552d0633ebd59dbc1359e78cb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-compiler.js?hash=70fc26c6c7dc707b63b03b4fed8f0493f1f6f50b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript.js?hash=d72e1e42e0f96668a94070ef58b6e4eef8f948c9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/shell-server.js?hash=36a44317c7503a912dd277b1a73dbd5e3c8cda05"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime.js?hash=0b0630a8e3876158a622073f308de6885b7cd8b9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-runtime.js?hash=f57e4d4083eaef17eec2acaa0bfcd0208ca32411"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/promise.js?hash=35d1ba6016c39a9ebe98cc51e8d6a753b6458b71"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/url.js?hash=b17f76f223e6c33b3a66db77c8e2fe550a0bad4d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/http.js?hash=bbe39bbf503d3b3462888a6871fa07f4dc94d9f2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=e6870cb1bd9ddd24def74ae5ab4f90255ff99ee2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=68534f17db9d88b5ccce3f07aad710eaa84443c2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?hash=7edac9184f1652211565c289897ec661ea5b14e2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/server-render.js?hash=2cddec83d320a8572a7e758d7562ca6878ebbef8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?hash=884c0f04552531e604be5ca6d94381bbf1550f5c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-rate-limiter.js?hash=8da38f36842be7d93edaaaeb8a3696e61aae284b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?hash=4e647356c7e32999dba2a8addb95400243528bb0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/localstorage.js?hash=9e6b5b17cb648386cf69d1fff225bdf6c960317d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?hash=5959317d7a0f1bc4d8f23ac6af69bd6d78e7b2ce"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/callback-hook.js?hash=6a38b86e781d45ae0a606d2a6def910c47fe1d13"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?hash=9f198731db45dae3de53bd7103e01e9421173e40"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?hash=faed986c6955587c13cda25dc9a4f102b9f22674"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?hash=8f5a52821d627c13f03f6c9f8691f2a0bc0831a4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?hash=03574af9b5218423b2e7b6d9bae433f2573596f1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?hash=2d5eb7caf513b973780e0d80dbbdc0df16d6dd3a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?hash=c9490b09a1a1d5375a52ce03119140ba81be8bf1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-common.js?hash=96087f3a31518f03b650bc3a210af291022bd749"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?hash=1404b4f6c8537cfd3aab0f7ec0dc4bac698f60ea"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=72635ce5679ec1ac0e7425eed1e4282bcd750118"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/diff-sequence.js?hash=c2915458c9e591f6f100ec762ace098148467694"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-id.js?hash=a1be6d230d8c489a687edf8bf9a64e520b34d3aa"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a28bac54f0b5e59716ced19be6e63c849a6a4448"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?hash=dae39f35e2956c6df4d8b9963eea38371d546176"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?hash=9fb624fd53e827248a46955fc6a188dfe4f38306"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?hash=d6e5219c163c4774a73956f410e7c2565d39634b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?hash=04456b5cba2949764c60f0809ae5cf78590bcd67"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-server.js?hash=e223ea6838454ff7911f92e94a6776f469ecdd86"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/allow-deny.js?hash=38f77ee2f5b9c7d3fe6074e68b10ac22cf390925"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-dev-server.js?hash=b0d3e5c65cc159fb99b99b78e94b31117a4f27dd"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?hash=f70e3bfe4cc05b9ab7dc360ca483fa530d45ebc6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?hash=e15504227515793c40a6a3a8ad340399cb657500"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=5da2e60ce61e074a6463979f3992dd5bac41b43d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?hash=8dd5bf14c21ee50b5a8e56bbba9b6df7da0d9db6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/htmljs.js?hash=66c4fe583b65fd634fd9bd550c9a701a27b45a7a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze.js?hash=cbd85c3fe14949f2d2b9a3b76334f5f0e96d553c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-base.js?hash=074cec43f8a104b136cf3a8fba686c6a5b470acd"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/alanning_roles.js?hash=a54a6feed3cf79dfe29122d3d32ea075c4f3dd01"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-compiler.js?hash=bbfa4e036fd01e80e52aa0778d35051e34769351"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-runtime.js?hash=0d383d6c0c2772772a6e7c4451eca7cb8f6a7559"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?hash=f2c84fce6d8b04d2702ff547986293031866f706"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tmeasday_publish-counts.js?hash=3c15c9f70b102b5a3a265ed860c0b2d0973b46e5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_simple-schema.js?hash=585c9232f73d1b42ab796bbfc658572cbd58a227"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/raix_eventemitter.js?hash=4885ec4caa7f4d74ebb64d9fac5ec912b873ce4a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tmeasday_check-npm-versions.js?hash=650f4b079080dfef5e50011c0b63762a6fc486c0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=820d37c4488f283b07ec8a84d5f3c3d8940fb1e1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mobile-experience.js?hash=d972574740885ebc90d0cf457bac918b8c4e9627"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/johanbrook_publication-collector.js?hash=2a82528012b3bef7411143eb26fd09bb4d14248a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/sha.js?hash=908fd819e631f3400f2f23afb3a4af3aae9e37e1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/srp.js?hash=ddcd66cbf787c22ab028bdff559e1329c5d83b11"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-password.js?hash=e789b7891e9ce767d04c321654877c94bbce4ef9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mizzao_timesync.js?hash=addbf3ed1c553f9413975a3fb8d1208fb916d76c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mizzao_user-status.js?hash=0a56aeb05728cbb0beb63c9f707e27e5f5885f0a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/email.js?hash=c2922918596f9b360bca43bb2812dca7814fb544"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/chfritz_easycron.js?hash=715c8eb2725898de9dc967d645f2cac7c3a0d3c0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ostrio_cookies.js?hash=03aa20c1bc21b74d470a1cd674cf11cc7cda9222"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ostrio_files.js?hash=4edb6cfc5f4fe1a4f300aae822672e44fc7d5d65"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/konecty_mongo-counter.js?hash=e5933210771e592bbb194172afe4a7d3cd8ad59c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/fentas_mapreduce.js?hash=98ea4c56f3783151ca6cea83a12a9207bdbca858"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_ssr.js?hash=a33f7a814753bc531da66e259f8387008827eb90"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze-html-templates.js?hash=a708f196d92ee052ed42df1f8d9071d3bc189323"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?hash=cbcad55cc58278a0ec0a580e1dfc4582ed0f6c91"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ui.js?hash=73201242e628677db1e85e5024826e6b9b4ede91"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/global-imports.js?hash=181f5b96aa49ee584d0414c0b4c65aa5be5c42b8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js?hash=88c66d8e2d037df8004e28a1b64a514b3dc623fe"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/service-configuration.js?hash=208fb9e31f62e02cfd404cde75672b80778161aa"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mdg_validation-error.js?hash=a7a0d4ca9a11ac7783ccdd9cc5e5b517a64bb18f"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

While header part still belong to my code, the body part appears automatically and it doesn't load the rest of codes, such as the remaining .js or .css files.

My package.json is as below:

```
{
  "name": "web-crm",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "dialog-polyfill": "^0.4.10",
    "fast-html-parser": "^1.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "getmdl-select": "^1.0.4",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "history": "^3.3.0",
    "mantra-core-extra": "^1.8.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.15.0",
    "numeral": "^1.5.3",
    "pad-number": "0.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "15.3.2",
    "react-alert": "^4.0.4",
    "react-daterange-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.1.0",
    "react-komposer": "^2.0.0",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-mounter": "^1.0.0",
    "react-pager": "^1.1.4",
    "react-photoswipe": "^1.2.0",
    "react-popover": "^0.4.4",
    "react-portal": "^4.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.9",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^3.1.2",
    "react-router": "^3.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-router-scroll": "^0.4.4",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-simple-di-extra": "^1.3.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "scroll-behavior": "0.9.3",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "simpl-schema": "^1.5.6",
    "style": "0.0.3",
    "truncate": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.8.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@babel/cli": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-require": "3.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.4.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "jsdom": "13.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "4.8.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.3.2",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.x",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "test/main.js"
  }
}
```

While my .meteor/packages is as below:

```
meteor@1.7.0                  # Shared foundation for all Meteor packages
standard-minifier-css@1.4.1   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.3.4    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command
alanning:roles
tmeasday:publish-counts
aldeed:simple-schema
mongo@1.5.0
aldeed:collection2
mobile-experience@1.0.5
reactive-var@1.0.11
tracker@1.2.0
meteortesting:mocha
johanbrook:publication-collector
accounts-password
mizzao:user-status
email
chfritz:easycron
ostrio:files
konecty:mongo-counter
fentas:mapreduce
meteorhacks:ssr
dynamic-import
tmeasday:check-npm-versions
jquery
server-render
webapp
angular-compilers
ecmascript
```

NOTE: This project was using webpack to run and bundle previously, but I can't really use webpack as compiler as it is giving me lots of **import** (ECMA) errors.

Any help will be great.  Been stucked like forever.

Comment: If 1.6 wasn't working for you, then I would not go to 1.7 just yet. Clearly something broken between 1.4 and 1.6 in your app. Also, 1.7 had some issues, so once you are done getting things working in 1.6, I would recommend to upgrade to 1.8 directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. However, it was due to 1.6 was having more "unexplainable" errors during compile, thus making me to believe that 1.6.0.1 and 1.6.1 had issues.  Thus going for 1.7.  At least the errors during compilation no longer exists now.

Comment: Is there anyone providing service to help in compile and bundling? Am rather hurry to resolve this matter. :(

Comment: @ChristianFritz your project is running on 1.8 currently?

Comment: not just one project, but yes. Meteor is very stable and reliable. Just version 1.7 was a bit of a hick-up, but I doubt that what you are facing is even related to that. You seem to just not know what is contained in your project and hence cannot tell which breaking changes affect you and in what way.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve the above (but if you are willing to upgrade to React-Router v4 however a painful process): https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4477 .  Upgrade to 4.0.8 helps, don't go for 5.0.0-beta-x.

Hard way to solve the above but relatively easier is to stick to React-Router v3 (or upgrade from v2) then fix all the errors one-by-one.  E.g.

- Check if the imports are correctly done, with or without { } .  Thanks to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12214#issuecomment-364816083
- Check if the imports are still valid.  For example, react-alert is having API such as Provider instead of AlertContainer